# Delete ghost guest folders

Tags: login

Can I safely delete the "**guest-*WEIRDCODE***" folders created in the **/media** folder everytime someone logs in using the guest-session option? (using Ubuntu 13.04)

[image]

**EDIT:** Sorry, I can not reply to the answers so I do it here:

@gabrielf : Yes, they persist. I agree they should be removed by the system, but for some reason they are not =(

@gunnar-hjalmarsson : I also agree with you, they should be removed. Thank you for proposing the code change.

As both of you said, this folder contains the user folders, from which the user can access the hard disk partitions/USB stick contents once they are mounted.

Now my question is... can I safely delete them manually? is it safe? Or should I use some command because there's some system file that must be updated or something?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't these folders be created under /tmp/guest-*? Maybe these are folders to USB mounted devices by guest... anyway, I believe it shouldn't persist after the guest user logs out. If you restart your computer (to make sure you close all active sessions), the folders remain there?

Comment: I answered that question. "Yes you can" means "Yes you can safely delete them manually". ;-)

Comment: @gunnar-hjalmarsson My bad. For some reason my eyes skipped that line of text. My brain must have taken it for a username/date header or something. Thank you and sorry! =)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Those folders are not created **every** time someone logs in to a guest session, but they are created as needed for instance if a guest user inserts a USB stick.

Personally I think it would make sense if the program tried to remove the possible /media folder at the logout from a guest session, so [I have proposed such a code change](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~lightdm-team/lightdm/trunk/revision/1864.1.3).